# Obtener información antes de enviar formulario

Tags: javascript

Tengo un formulario

```
<form action="/consultas" method="post">
```

quiero hacer una peticion ajax para obtener si aun puedo enviar un mensaje, antes de enviar el formulario

```
$('.enviarFormulario').click(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({

                    });
        )
        });
```

es posible, como seria el código que no logro implementarlo?

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. Y, [en Stackoverflow hay varias preguntas sobre Ajax](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax?sort=votes&pageSize=50) cuyas respuestas explican cómo funciona. ¿Por qué no te inspiras en alguno de ellos para partir de una base sólida, en caso de que no te funcione?

Comment: @A.Cedano quiero enviar una peticion ajax antes de enviar el submit esta bien mi idea?

Comment: No te puedo decir si tu idea está bien sin conocer el contexto de tu aplicación. Eso es lo que determinará si está bien o no. Por ejemplo, hay peticiones Ajax que se envían antes del  submit para llenar campos del mismo formulario tomando datos del servidor etc, y hay formularios que se envían enteros con el submit o sin él. Lo determinante es **qué hace tu aplicación, para qué usas ese formulario**, dependiendo de eso debes entonces decidir lo que sea mejor, conociendo que se puede hacer de cualquiera de las maneras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar una variable parametros

```
var param = {input1: $("#idinput1").val(), ...} //aqui en el array metes los que necesites
```

y luego se lo pasas a la llamada a ajax:

```
$.ajax({
// la URL para la petición
url : 'post.php',

// la información a enviar
// (también es posible utilizar una cadena de datos)
data : param,

// especifica si será una petición POST o GET
type : 'POST',

// el tipo de información que se espera de respuesta
dataType : 'json',

// código a ejecutar si la petición es satisfactoria;
// la respuesta es pasada como argumento a la función
success : function(json) {
    //aqui recibes la respuesta del mensaje y para llamar al form creo que se hace con la siguiente linea
    //Si .enviarFormulario es el boton del submit del form seria asi
    $('.enviarFormulario').submit();
},


});
```

Comment: funciono    gracias !!!